# CentOS 7 Cannot Install MySQL 5.7 nothing I have done works still trys to instll mariadb

Tags: centos, mysql

I have followed just about every instruction, including the instruction from MySQL and following instrucitons from around web including this site.

I have downloaded the mysql57-community-release-el7-11.noarch.rpm i have disabled with yum ocnfig manager mariadb and removed maria db I have enabled MySQL 5.7 and when i do rpm -qa|grep mysql

cpanel-mysql-5.1.73-1.cp1156.x86_64
cpanel-perl-524-DBD-mysql-4.042-1.cp1168.x86_64
mysql57-community-release-el7-11.noarch
ea-php70-php-mysqlnd-7.0.27-5.5.7.cpanel.x86_64
cpanel-mysql-libs-5.1.73-1.cp1156.x86_64
ea-php55-php-mysqlnd-5.5.38-33.33.7.cpanel.x86_64
ea-php56-php-mysqlnd-5.6.33-6.6.5.cpanel.x86_64

rpm -qa|grep mariadb

does return

cpanel-mariadb-native-client-1.0.1-6.cp1154.x86_64
cpanel-mariadb-native-client-devel-1.0.1-6.cp1154.x86_64

I am on a cpanel installation and the host is of no use and client doesn't want to move from host. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: May I ask that if you are going to down vote please provide me with a way to correct what the issue is. 

I am really just reaching out to the open source community for a little guidance. If there is a way that I could improve this so it is not so offensive that it gets down voted, I would be happy to put the work in. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

If you need MySQL 5.7 support you’ll need to upgrade the machine to cPanel 70.x (https://releases.cpanel.net) and install it through WHM.

If you get stuck ask for help at https://tickets.cpanel.net/submit/